# Firebase Security Rules are working when on Localhost but not when Deployed on VERCEL

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, firebase-security

**POST https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel?VER=8&database=projects%2Fringtonedownloader-e8aae%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&gsessionid=d2XnM0a5gjA_QztOsE36S1h6MRDktfnP7TXH6UFbjqg&SID=kYIS51-cP7n_6NRbxiHVdA&RID=14377&TYPE=terminate&zx=svfev1gm8mej net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT**

This is Error I am Getting after Deploying. It works like a charm on localhost during dev.

Changed all the Security Rules to [true](/questions/tagged/true) and it works

But when Checking if there is a user it does not work!
This is my security Rules

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /ringtones/{ringtone=**}{
        allow read: if true;
      allow create: if isSignedIn();
      allow delete: if isSignedIn();
      allow update: if isSignedIn();
    }
  }
}

function isSignedIn() {
  return request.auth.uid != null;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this  stackoverflow [link1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73922740

Comment: I've Tried that, also I have said it works on Localhost but not after deploying :). So what happens is, the error log in console goes away but still doesn't do POST request when deployed